# Radha staying in Dwaraka

Tags: scripture, krishna, radha, garga-samhita

Till now, I thought that Radha generally live in [Barsana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsana) and she never live in Dwaraka.

But, the following statements clarify that Radha lived in Dwaraka also.

> After thus performing a rasa dance at Siddhashrama, Lord Krishna took
> the gopis and queens to Dvaraka. There He built many great palaces for
> Shri Radha.
>
> [[42-43, 18, 6, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_6.18:_In_the_Course_of_Describing_the_Glories_of_Siddhashrama,_a_Description_of_the_Rasa-dance_Festival)

And Narada tells about Radha palace also

> Shri Narada said: The size of Dvaraka is 800 miles. The path around it
> is 3,200 miles. In the center of Dvaraka is a fortress 96 miles in
> size. Around that Lord Krishna had built a second fortress of 180
> miles. O king, around that is a third fortress 400 miles in size and
> the place of with many jewel palaces. In the first fort Lord Krishna
> has 900,000 wonderful palaces. **O king, at the entrance to Shri
> Radha's palace, is Lila-sarovara lake, which was brought from Goloka,
> and which is the best of all holy places**.
>
> [[1-5, 19, 6, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_6.19:_In_the_First_Fortress_of_Dvaraka,_the_Glories_of_Lila-sarovara,_Hari-mandira,_Jnana-tirtha,_Krishna-kunda,_Balabhadra-sarah,_Ganesha-tirtha,_Dana-sthala,_and_Maya-tirtha)

Are there any other scriptural references stating the same fact that Radha lived in Dwaraka?